# Values got from programmed PID are different from ones simulated in Simulink

Tags: matlab, pid-controller, simulink

*Please also read Update*

I created a PID simulation in Simulink:

[image]

where the Step block is set with parameters:

```
Set time = 0
Initial value = 0 
Final value = 100 
Sample time = 0.01
```

And I coded the above PID in MATLAB:

```matlab
classdef PID < handle
    properties
        Kp = 0
        Ki = 0
        Kd = 0
        SetPoint = 1
        Dt = 0.01
    end
    
    properties (Access = private)
        IState = 0
        PreErr = 0
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = PID(Kp, Ki, Kd, SetPoint, Dt)
            if nargin == 0
                return;
            end
            obj.Kp = Kp;
            obj.Ki = Ki;
            obj.Kd = Kd;
            obj.SetPoint = SetPoint;
            obj.Dt = Dt;
        end
        
        function output = update(obj, measuredValue, t)
            err = obj.SetPoint - measuredValue;
            P = obj.getP(err);
            I = obj.getI(err);
            filter = lowPass(obj,t);
            D = obj.getD(err*filter);
            output = P + I + D;
        end
        
        function val = getP(obj, err)
            val = obj.Kp*err;
        end
        
        function val = getI(obj, err)
            obj.IState = obj.IState + err * obj.Dt;
            val = obj.Ki * obj.IState;
        end
        
        function val = getD(obj, err)
            val = obj.Kd * (err - obj.PreErr) / obj.Dt;            
            obj.PreErr = err;
        end
        
        function val = lowPass(obj,t)
            N = 1;
            val = 1-exp(-N*t);
        end
    end
end
```

The transfer function same as the one in the Simulink:

```matlab
function r = getResponse(t)
r = 0.2 - 0.2*exp(-5*t);
end
```

And the code for the programmatic simulation:

```matlab
sr = 1e2; % sampling rate 100Hz
st = 10; % sampling time 10s
ss = st*sr+1; % sample size
t = 0:1/sr:st; % time

input = ones(1,ss)*100;
output = zeros(1,ss);
measured = 0;

pid = PID(0,1,0,input(1),t(2)-t(1)); %Kp=0,Ki=1,Kd=0
for i = 2:ss
    rPID(i) = pid.update(measured, t(i));
    output(i) = rPID(i)*getResponse(t(i));    
    measured = output(i);
end
figure;
hold on;
plot(t,output)
plot(t,input)
plot(t,rPID)
legend('Output','Input','PID')
```

I have confirmed that when `Kp=1; Ki=0; Kd=0;`, both simulations yield the *exact* same result. But when I set `Kp=0; Ki=1; Kd=0;`, the results are different.

Simulink result:

[image]

Programmatic simulation result:

[image]

As you can see, not only the final values are completely different, but the difference starts from the very beginning at the first time stamp 0.01s. I can't think of how Simulink does the calculation and where my mistake is. (I know I must have some mistake in low pass filter -> the derivative term, but they are isolated from this example.)

The last time I did control system was years ago in undergraduate, so I must have made some very fundamental mistakes.

---

## Update

I recalculated the inverse Laplace transformation. It turns out my previous calculation is incorrect. The correct `getResponse` function is:

```
function r = getResponse(t)
r = 1 - exp(-5*t);
end
```

After this correction, the result looks much similar:

[image]

However, there is still some minor differences. Here's a figure showing the difference (programmatic simulation result - Simulink):

[image]

Comment: did you try \$\frac {10s}{s+10}\$ for the differentiator path?

Comment: @Chu the differential path is completely off for some reason. The values go sky rock after several seconds kept increasing to infinity. But I set kd = 0 so these minor error can't be attributed to anything else but the integral path.

Comment: I wouldn't expect them to be identical, because you certainly haven't modelled your actual system with zero error. Looking at the graph, the difference seems to be small enough that it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Hearth the plant is simply a random low pass filter not near any representation of the actual system. I'm only trying to refresh my memory on PID (mostly re-study).

Comment: Oh, I see; I had thought you were using a physical system. Note to self, read the entire question before commenting next time.

Comment: @Hearth can't blame you, this is a *long* post.

Comment: Have you set the initial value of the integrator in PID to the same value in both cases?

Comment: @Hazem yes I have. They are both zero